# Намеренное искажение цитаты

Tags: недопустимая-метка, терминология, цитата

Каким термином в литературоведении можно обозначить стилистический прием, когда намеренно искажается цитата, крылатое слово, или афоризм. К примеру "Бить или не бить",

Answer (score 2):

То что вы привели в качестве примера, называют игрой слов, или каламбуром

Answer (score 2):

В качестве литературного приема это может быть охарактеризовано как **контекстная модификация** крылатого выражения. Если при этом выражение приобретает комический эффект, то да, оно становится еще и каламбуром. Но контекстной модификацией быть не перестает.
Другого общего термина я сейчас что-то не вспомню.

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях обычно говорят о перефразированных выражениях, цитатах и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Каламбур. Но — не на пустом месте, что обязывает давать справку типа «как говаривал...», если цитируемый известен. Ответ: каламбур в соавторстве или соавторский.